# Why is a newline inside a heredoc inside a command substitution lost by bash (but not dash)?

Tags: bash

When run in bash, this command:

```sh
cat <<EOF
hello \\
world
EOF
```

will output as I expect:

```
hello \
world
```

But this one outputs `hello \world` (without the newline), and is unexpected:

```sh
echo "$(cat <<EOF
hello \\
world
EOF
)"
```

If I run the second command with dash, then the output is as expected (with a newline).

Why is the newline removed in 2nd command in bash?

Comment: bash 3.2.57 prints a newline with the second command.  In which version of bash do you see the behavior you describe?

Comment: If you don't want the shell to interpret backslashes as special inside your heredoc, quote the sigil. `<<'EOF'`, not `<<EOF`

Comment: @WilliamPursell, this is reproducible on bash 5.0.3 -- see https://ideone.com/bEiM2H

Comment: I can also repro it on bash v4.2.10 (and v4.3.48 and v5.0.3), but not v3.2.57.

Comment: BTW, replacing `cat` with `xxd` makes it clear this is something happening with the here-document before it's sent to the command as input. Also, I get the same result when the here-doc delimiter is quoted. I do *not* get weird results using backticks instead of `$()` (well, other than the usual pre-parsing of backslashes that always happens inside backticks).

Comment: Related: [Non-expanding here-documents inside command substitution are subject to newline joining](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-02/msg00023.html)

Comment: I confirm the same behaviour with `bash` 5.1.8. And I also confirm that quoting the sigil (`'EOF'`) solves the issue (but you'll need to use only one backslash to get the expected result).

Comment: even quoting the sigil works with bash 5.0.3 but does not work with 4.4

Comment: I tested this in bash 2.00.0(2), 3.2.57(1), 4.0.0(1), 4.4.0(1), and 5.1.0(1). Seems like this bug (?) was introduced in bash 4 and stayed since then. Before that version everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are re-parsing the output again, so the double-backslash has already been parsed, and the now-single backslash is quoting the newline, making it a continuation line.

Take them both out and it works as you'd expect.

---

## EDIT

See comments below.
I'd delete the answer, but the useful comments would go as well.

Comment: ... I'm not sure this is a satisfactory explanation. Command substitution results don't go through all parsing steps -- just string splitting and glob expansion, and even those are suppressed by quoting, do where exactly does this extra parsing pass come from?

Comment: As Charles Duffy said: a quoted `"$(...)"` should not be parsed again by bash. The command itself could parse its arguments, but bash's builtin `echo` does not do so without `-n` and even `printf %s` shows the same problem.

Comment: Using `"$(cat <<EOF >&2 ...` shows that the linebreak is removed before `"$( )"` is fully expanded, so the problem is not re-parsing of any sort. I'm pretty sure this is a bug in bash.